# Using an integer value from a class in another class

Tags: c#, class, console-application

Please I am trying to get the values from this class:

```
class MovieRating
{
    // This block of code is to get user ratings of the movie
    public void DetailsRate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Rate the Acting on a scale of 0 to 5");
         RateActing = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("\n Rate the music of the movie on a scale of 0 to 5");
        RateMusic = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Rate the cinematography of the movie on a scale of 0 to 5");

        Console.WriteLine("Rate the plot of the movie on a scale of 0 to 5");
        Console.WriteLine("Rate the duration of the movie on a scale of 0 to 5");
        RateDuratn = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    }
}
```

And use it in this class:

```
class Executerating
{
    public void  overallRate()
    {
        MovieRating movrate = new MovieRating();
        int rateact = movrate.RateActing;
        int ratemus = movrate.RateMusic;
        int ratecin = movrate.RateCinema;
        int rateplot = movrate.RatePlot;
        int ratedur = movrate.RateDuratn;

        int totrate = rateact + ratemus + ratecin + rateplot + ratedur;


        Console.WriteLine("total rate is- {0}", totrate);
    }
```

But I discovered that no value is entering the class

> 'Executerating'

Please what am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks like the call to the DetailsRate() method is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to call `DetailsRate()` in `overallRate()`, i.e.

```
...
MovieRating movrate = new MovieRating();
movrate.DetailsRate();
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and it worked I was able to get the values from the class but at the point of execution this variable  "int totrate" gives only this value "int rateact = movrate.RateActing" please kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Convert `DetailsRate` method in `MovieRate` contructor:

```
public MovieRate() {
    // DetailsRate code
}
```

Or call it statically instead of create an instance

```
MovieRate.DetailsRate();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add properties to your code as follows:

```
Class MovieRating
{
  public int RateActing { get; set; }
  public int RateMusic { get; set; }
  public int RateDuratn { get; set; }

    public void DetailsRate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Rate the Acting on a scale of 0 to 5");
         RateActing = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("\n Rate the music of the movie on a scale of 0 to 5");
        RateMusic = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Rate the cinematography of the movie on a scale of 0 to 5");

        Console.WriteLine("Rate the plot of the movie on a scale of 0 to 5");
        Console.WriteLine("Rate the duration of the movie on a scale of 0 to 5");
        RateDuratn = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    }
}
```